# NodeJS can't load css file

Tags: javascript, html, css, node.js

So I'm trying to make a NodeJS server, and I try to keep as few add-ons as possible.

However, I have hit a problem, I don't seem to be able to load any `CSS` files called by my `HTML` files. The call do seem to be processed by the server, but it doesn't show in the browser.

My **webserver.js** file

```
// A very basic web server in node.js
// Stolen from: Node.js for Front-End Developers by Garann Means (p. 9-10) 

var port = 8000;
var serverUrl = "localhost";

var http = require("http");
var path = require("path"); 
var fs = require("fs");         

console.log("Starting web server at " + serverUrl + ":" + port);

http.createServer( function(req, res) {

    var now = new Date();

    var filename = req.url || "index.html";
    var ext = path.extname(filename);
    var localPath = __dirname;
    var validExtensions = {
        ".html" : "text/html",          
        ".js": "application/javascript", 
        ".css": "text/css",
        ".txt": "text/plain",
        ".jpg": "image/jpeg",
        ".gif": "image/gif",
        ".png": "image/png",
        ".ico": "image/png"
    };
    var isValidExt = validExtensions[ext];

    if (isValidExt) {
        localPath += filename;

        fs.exists(localPath, function(exists) {
            if(exists) {
                console.log("Serving file: " + localPath);
                getFile(localPath, res, ext);
            } else {
                console.log("File not found: " + localPath);

                if(ext === 'text/html'){
                    getFile(__dirname + '/404.html', res, ext);
                }
            }
        });

    } else {
         console.log("Invalid file extension detected: " + ext)
         getFile(__dirname + '/index.html', res, 'text/html');
    }

}).listen(port, serverUrl);

function getFile(localPath, res, mimeType) {
    fs.readFile(localPath, function(err, contents) {
        if(!err) {
            res.setHeader("Content-Length", contents.length);
            res.setHeader("Content-Type", mimeType);
            res.statusCode = 200;
            res.end(contents);
        } else {
            res.writeHead(500);
            res.end();
        }
    });
}
```

and the **index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <p>
            Hello
        </p>
    </body>
</html>
```

**style.css**

```
p{
    color: red;
}
```

**server log**

```
$ node webserver
Starting web server at localhost:8000
Serving file: c:\Users\MichaelTot\Desktop\Code Projects\Web\nodeJS/index.html
Serving file: c:\Users\MichaelTot\Desktop\Code Projects\Web\nodeJS/style.css
```

**client log**

```
Resource interpreted as Stylesheet but transferred with MIME type text/plain: "http://127.0.0.1:8000/style.css".
```

Comment: What does the log show?

Comment: Just added the log ^^

Comment: Does `http://127.0.0.1:8000/style.css` contain the content you expect when you look at it?

Comment: try this
        `res.setHeader("Content-Type", "text/html");`
(also you might want to look into the express framework or hapi or something similar)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is here :

```
getFile(localPath, res, ext);
```

You give `ext` to `getFile`, but according to the function signature, you are waiting for the mimetype. So you should do this :

```
getFile(localPath, res, validExtensions[ext]);
```

The browser don't read the css because by default NodeJS use the `text/plain` mimetype. But the browser wants a `text/css` mimetype for a css file.