# How to enqueue CSS and JS to a page on the fly with NodeJS app file

Tags: javascript, node.js

I need to get HTML page, enqueue CSS and JS files to it "on the fly" and then display it in the browser with NodeJS app file. I mean without changing HTML code of the page before getting it by NodeJS. Both CSS and JS files are in the same folder as NodeJS app file.

I'm trying this way

```
var fs = require('fs');
var http = require('http');
http.createServer(function (req, res) {
if(req.url === '/favicon.ico') {
    res.writeHead(404);
    res.end();
    return;
}

var indexPageHTML = fs.readFileSync('index.html');
var indexPageHTML = indexPageHTML.toString();
var indexPageHTML = indexPageHTML.split('</head>')[0]+'<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css"></head>'+indexPageHTML.split('</head>')[1];
var indexPageHTML = indexPageHTML.split('</body>')[0]+'<script src="my_client_script.js"></script></body></html>';

res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html; charset=utf8'});
res.end(indexPageHTML);
}).listen(80, 'localhost');
```

my minified **index.html**

```
<!doctype html><html><head><meta charset="utf-8"><title>Homepage title</title>
<style>html,body{height:100%;}</style></head><body>
<header></header>
<main role="main"></main>
<footer></footer>
</body></html>
```

In the browser I get the code I need, but none of files are loaded (CSS are not applied and JS doesn't work on the page) and in the browser console I get the error

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <

and the warning

> Resource interpreted as Stylesheet but transferred with MIME type
>   text/html: "http://localhost/app_style.css".

How to resolve the problem?

ps. I'm working with NodeJS in local computer on disk C inside of `C:/User/Username`

Comment: You are serving the same `HTML` in response to every request. Even the request for the `styles.css` was receiving the HTML content.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I've found the answer by the link [NodeJS can't load css file](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33280981/3208225)

Just added the code

```
...
if(mimeType == 'text/html') {
    var contents = contents.toString();
    var contents = contents.split('</head>')[0]+'<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css"></head>'+contents.split('</head>')[1];
    var contents = contents.split('</body>')[0]+'<script src="my_client_script.js"></script></body></html>';
}
res.end(contents);
...
```

to the `getFile()` function